# Factory unable to create objects defined within an IIFE object

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a gallery which transitions slides based on various Transition objects:

```
window.myGallery = (function () {
var instance = null;
    ....

//Base Transition
function Transition(slide, settings){
    this.slide = slide;
    this.el = slide.el;
    this.settings = settings;
    this.duration = (this.settings['transitionSpeed'] / 1000) + 's';
    this.endAnimation = null;
}

//FADE TRANSITION
function FadeTransition(slide, settings){
    Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
}
FadeTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition.prototype);
FadeTransition.prototype.constructor = FadeTransition;

//SLIDE TRANSITION
function SlideTransition(slide, settings){
    Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
}
SlideTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition.prototype);
SlideTransition.prototype.constructor = SlideTransition;
```

To get the appropriate transition object, I built this factory:

```
 var TransitionFactory = function () {
    return {
        createTransition: function (slide, transitionType, settings) {
            if (transitionType) {
                type = transitionType;
            }
            if (type == 'fade') {
                return new FadeTransition(slide, settings);
            }
            else if(type == 'slide'){
                return new SlideTransition(slide, settings);
            }

        },
        //Set default transition
        type: "fade"
    };
};
```

Since I envision dozens of different transitions, I thought I would be clever and take in a string to create the transition object dynamically:

```
 createTransition: function (slide, transitionType, settings) {
            if (transitionType) {
                type = transitionType;
            }
            type = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
            type += 'Transition';
            if(typeof window[type] != 'undefined') //BOOM
                return new window[type](slide, settings);
            else
                return new FadeTransition(slide, settings);

        },
```

The issue is `FadeTransition` is defined within the IIFE assigned to `window.myGallery`, since I don't want to pollute the global scope with all my objects. Therefore, this will always be `undefined`:

```
   if(typeof window[type] != 'undefined')
```

How can I test for the existence of an object within the IIFE scope and instantiate it if it does exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the inner functions can be accessed in IIFE, but if I were to do it, I would have added all those functions in an object, based on the user's input I would have picked the function from the object. Here is a sample implementation.

```
var myGallery = (function() {
    var instance = null;

    //NOTE: Base Transition Function goes here

    function inheriter(child, parent) {
        child.prototype = Object.create((parent || Transition).prototype);
        child.prototype.constructor = child;
    }

    var transitions = {
        FadeTransition: function(slide, settings) {
            Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
        },
        SlideTransition: function(slide, settings) {
            Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
        }
    };

    for (var transition in transitions) {
        inheriter(transitions[transition], Transition);
    }

    return {
        createTransition: function(slide, transitionType, settings) {
            type = (transitionType || "fade") + "Transition";
            type = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
            if (!transitions[type]) {
                type = "FadeTransition";
            }
            return new transitions[type](slide, settings);
        }
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from this question is you're doing something like

```
window.foo = (function () {
    function Fizz() {
        return buzz();
    }
    function buzz() {
        return 'fizzbuzz';
    }
    return Fizz;
}());
```

And you're asking

> How can I do `buzz();` outside the *IIFE*?

Well, unless you are passing a reference to `buzz` out of the *IIFE* which isn't happening here, you can't.

However, in *JavaScript*, you can use almost everything like an *Object* and this can enable you to pass a reference out without polluting your namespace.

```
Fizz.buzz = buzz; // before return Fizz
```

Now you can access `buzz` as `window.foo.buzz`. If you're still not happy with this because it's a property on a *Function*, use an *Object* as your namespace instead

```
return {
    "Fizz": Fizz,
    "buzz": buzz
};
```